# HttpSessionListener throws exception?

Tags: servlets, exception

Can HttpSessionListener throw exceptions?

- If yes, to where do they go? In what point is the stack interrupted?
- If no, how should I treat exceptions there? Logging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Can HttpSessionListener throw exceptions?*

The interface itself doesn't throw anything. It's only **your own** code in the concrete implementation which *can* do that.

---

> *If yes, to where do they go? In what point is the stack interrupted?*

The container catches it, logs it to the server log, ignores the failed call and then continues the job it is supposed to do.

---

> *If no, how should I treat exceptions there? Logging?*

Write robust code so that you've eliminated all code bugs (which may cause `RuntimeException`s). Put if necessary a `try-catch` around uncontrollable exception-sensitive code in the implementation yourself so that you can handle it yourself on whatever sensible manner you think you need to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

HttpSessionListener is an interface, so the answers to your questions will depend upon your implementation. If your implementation can throw an Exception, you should at least log it. If you need to display something to the user, you could stick something in the session and then have a javax.servlet.Filter look for that key, etc.